# Preciso copiar um valor que está no "value". Estou utilizando Eclipse Java Biblioteca Selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

Este é o html:

```
input name="nr_proposta" type="text" value="52367" data-mask="9?99999999" data-mask-placeholder=" " class="form-control apagar" id="nr_proposta"
```

Em java estou fazendo assim:

```
WebElement nrProposta = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(1)"));
WebElement nrProposta2 = driver.findElement(By.name("nr_proposta"));

System.out.println("N Proposta:       " + nrProposta.getText());         
System.out.println("N Proposta:2      " + nrProposta2.getText());
```

Desta maneira me retorna `null` ou em branco...

Quando utilizo `nrProposta.getAttribute("value");` ele me retorna `null`.

Comment: quando vc dar o nrProposta.toString() ele retorna a tag toda?

Answer (score 0):

Você tem 2 maneiras,
pode tentar pegar oque esta visível no elemento com o

> `nrProposta.getText()`

que acredito que no seu caso seja suficiente.

ou pegar um atributo do elemento com o `

> nrProposta.getAttribute("nomeDoAtributoDesejado")

`